# Sorting dir.list() path list does not seem to work with filename having '-'

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a array with filenames alphabetically.
Piece of the datacollection:

```
****** Unsorted String Array *******
5396-1.jpg
5396.jpg
5396-2.jpg
5560.jpg
5561.jpg
```

When sorting the array with : `Arrays.sort(pathList, Collections.reverseOrder());` (either reversed or not), I don't get the wanted result.

```
****** Sorted (Reversed) String Array *******
5560.jpg
5561.jpg
5396.jpg
5396-2.jpg
5396-1.jpg

****** Sorted String Array *******
5396-1.jpg
5396-2.jpg
5396.jpg
5560.jpg
5561.jpg
```

As you may notice in the (reversed sorting) the order is following:

```
5396.jpg
5396-2.jpg
5396-1.jpg
```

Where the wanted result needs to be:

```
5396.jpg
5396-1.jpg
5396-2.jpg
```

Can anybody help me in sorting the array the correct way keeping eye on the divider `'-'` which does not order correctly using the `Array.sort`

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to write your own `Comparator` and then use [`Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))

Comment: So it should "orignally" sort it to "5396-2.jpg", "5396-1.jpg", "5396.jpg", ... (we're talking about the reversed array)? The standard sorting doesn't work like that with obvios reasons ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `String`s in Java are sorted lexicographically. From the Javadoc of `String.compareTo(string)`:

> If two strings are different, then either they have different
>   characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or
>   their lengths are different, or both. If they have different
>   characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such
>   index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller
>   value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically
>   precedes the other string. [...]
>
> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string.

Given your unsorted array, this means that at some point `-` (e.g. in 5396-1.jpg) will be compared to `.` (in 5396.jpg). Since `-` has a smaller value than `.` 5396-1.jpg will be sorted before 5396.jpg.

However, if you strip the extension (`.jpg`), the second paragraph of the Javadoc comes into play. Since 5396 is shorter than 5396-1 the former will be sorted before the latter.

To solve your problem, use a `Comparator` that ignores the extension:

```
public class IgnoreExtensionComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String s1WithoutExtension = s1.substring(0, s1.lastIndexOf("."));
        String s2WithoutExtension = s2.substring(0, s2.lastIndexOf("."));
        return s1WithoutExtension.compareTo(s2WithoutExtension);
    }
}
```

Then sort your array with:

```
Arrays.sort(filenames, new IgnoreExtensionComparator());
```

Given your unsorted array, this produces the following order:

```
5396.jpg
5396-1.jpg
5396-2.jpg
5560.jpg
5561.jpg
```

Comment: Wooow fanastic explanation! Now i exactly understand what's going on. Thank you very much @hzpz!!!

Answer (score -2):

Try writing a `Comparator` that ignores the extension of the file name, that should put everything into the desired order. :)

Comment: @ChthonicProject Actually, Jens is right (although very brief). See my answer.

Comment: @hzpz - thank you for correcting my mistake. I didn't realize that `.` was larger than `-`. Unfortunately, I can't change my vote unless the answer is edited.